# Cannot run pyspark in windows 10

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i'm a newbie in using apache spark.

I try to install but have problem to start pyspark using command prompt in Windows 10.

After install and set all environment variable, I'm manage to display Spark version 2.2.1, Anaconda version 4.4.10 and Python version 3.6.3

These are the environment variable that i set :

1) `HADOOP_HOME = C:\spark\hadoop`

2) `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151`

3) `SPARK_HOME = C:\spark\spark\bin`

4) `PYSPARK_PYTHON = C:\Users\niezaellya\Miniconda3\python.exe`

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of info - edit & update your post instead

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `C:\spark\spark\bin` in the `Path` variable separated by `;`

then **after reloading the environment variables**, you can type `pyspark` in command line for *python shell* and `spark-shell` for *scala shell*

and your `SPARK_HOME` shouldn't include `bin` which should be

```
SPARK_HOME = C:\spark\spark
```

Comment: I have set the path C:\spark\spark\bin previously and try to delete bin in SPARK_HOME, but still not working until i uninstall miniconda and reinstall anaconda again.. Now i manage to use pyspark. Tq Ramesh.. :)